# Now that SSLSocketFactory is deprecated on Android, what would be the best way to handle Client Certificate Authentication?

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp, pkcs#12, sslsocketfactory

I am working on an Android app that requires Client Certificate Authentication (with PKCS 12 files). 
Following the deprecation of all that's `apache.http.*`, we have started a pretty big work of refactoring on our network layer, and we have decided to go with OkHttp as a replacement, and so far I like that very much.

However, I haven't found any other way to handle client certificate auth without using `SSLSocketFactory`, with OkHttp or anything else for that matter. So what would be the best course of action in this particular case?
Is there another way with OkHttp to handle this sort of authentication?

Comment: `SSLSocketFactory` is not deprecated, either in the [current shipping versions of Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) or in the M Developer Preview.

Comment: Oh my god you are absolutely right, I never realised there were 2 classes SSLSocketFactory! org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is deprecated but javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory is not! Thanks a lot for this enlightenment.

Comment: Conversely, I had not realized that HttpClient had their own `SSLSocketFactory` class. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently, there are two `SSLSocketFactory` classes. HttpClient has its own one, and that is deprecated along with the rest of HttpClient. However, everybody else will be using [the more conventional `javax.net.ssl` edition of `SSLSocketFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), which is not deprecated (thank `$DEITY`).

Answer (score 54):

if you are using https, you have to use a valid certificate. During your dev stage you have to trust the certificate, how?
`sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory)` is deprecated and it's replaced by `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)`, you have to update your gradle file
the piece of code below will help you to get a trusted OkHttpClient that trusts any ssl certificate.

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
}
X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, the deprecated warning is removed simply by adding the trust manager.

Comment: I still get **SSLHandshakeException: connection closed by peer**

Comment: I'm not expert in NTLM, but may you need to use an external library as JCIFS.

Comment: There is no reference of certificate in the code.