# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on AndroidPlatform, sslSocketFactory

Tags: java, android, sockets

In my application,  I have integrated two libraries i.e. chat and video calling...The problem is when I open video library first, then both chat and video calling libraries are working fine but when I open the chat library first, and then open the video, it leads to an exception...I think it is a problem with sockets with default trustmangers..

Sample code I am using in video calling library to create sslcontext

```
trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                   }
                }
            };

            try {

                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**The exception I got this:**
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on AndroidPlatform, sslSocketFactory is class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl...Please help any one.

Comment: Please check your device time. its same with your time.

Comment: @MehulKabaria  thank you for reply yaa same time running in my device but its not works....

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened on emulator API 16 when I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/50264472/2914140 in this way:

```
val sslcontext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
sslcontext.init(null, null, null)
val tlsSocketFactory = TLSSocketFactory()

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .sslSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory)
    .build()
```

When I add a trustManager parameter to `sslSocketFactory` method, the exception disappears. But a problem with SSL connection doesn't disappear.

Comment: have you found a solution ? I'm in the same situation

Comment: @WaelFadlÃllåh, sorry, I removed a similar code from the application, because a system administrator fixed an issue on a server (as I understood, he fixed a certificate chain). But I can see what did before. When the problem appeared, I couldn't launch requests and couldn't download images with Glade.

Comment: @WaelFadlÃllåh, in my case another problem happened, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507560/2914140. Also I see that https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285550/2914140 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640113/2914140 helped me (a year ago), but later I removed https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640113/2914140.

Comment: @WaelFadlÃllåh, so, in the first link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507560/2914140) I wrote: `.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,
                trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)`.

Comment: can you point me to where I can study more about this matter ( sslSocketFactory)in depth

Comment: @WaelFadlÃllåh, sorry, I don't know, maybe https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/ssl-socket-factory/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002159/now-that-sslsocketfactory-is-deprecated-on-android-what-would-be-the-best-way-t can help.